# Induction on a collection of subspaces of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, induction

Is the proof of the following theorem correct?

**Theorem.** The intersection of every collection of subspaces of $V$ is a subspace of $V$.

**Proof.** Let the set $\mathcal{F}$ denote an arbitrary collection of subspaces of $V$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is defined as follows.
$$\mathcal{F}=\{U_1,U_2,U_3,...,U_{m-1},U_m\},\ m\in\mathbf{Z^+}$$

We seek to prove that $\cap \mathcal{F}=\bigcap_{j=1}^{m}U_j$ is a subspace of $V$ by recourse to *Mathematical Induction*.

*Basis-Step:* for $m=2$ we have $\bigcap_{j=1}^{2}U_j=U_1\cap U_2$, from **(10)** we know that $U_1\cap U_2$ is subspace of $V$.

*Inductive-Step:* Consider an arbitrary $k\in\{2,3,...,m-1\}$ and assume that $\bigcap_{j=1}^{k}U_j$ is a subspace of $V$.

Consider now the intersection $\bigcap_{j=1}^{k}U_j\cap U_{k+1}=\bigcap_{j=1}^{k+1}U_j$ again from **(10)** we see that this is a subspace of $V$, completing the inductive step.

We may now conclude that $\cap\mathcal{F}$ is subspace of $V$ and since $\mathcal{F}$ was an arbitrary collection of subspaces it follows that given any collection of subspaces there intersection is a subspace of $V$.

$\blacksquare$

*NOTE:* Here **(10)** represents the proposition that the intersection of any two subspaces of $V$ is another subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your proof is logically sound, it does not prove the claim at the beginning.  What you prove is the strictly weaker claim

> The intersection of any *finite* collection of subspaces is a subspace.

To prove that the intersection of an *arbitrary* collection $\mathcal F$ of subspaces of $V$ is a subspace of $V$, you have to allow $\mathcal F$ to have arbitrary cardinality.  So start off with
$$\mathcal F=\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A},$$
where each $U_\alpha$ is a subspace of $V$, then show that $\cap\mathcal F$ is a subspace.  This can be done using elementary set theory and the following proposition:

> A subset $U$ of a vector space $V$ is a vector subspace if and only if for every $x,y\in U$ and any scalars $\alpha$ and  $\beta$, we have $\alpha x+\beta y\in U$.